# Undefined is not a function in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jqgrid

I tried setting up jqGrid. I am using it with zend framework 2 and append these scripts in my view

```
echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath( 'js\jquery.min.js' ) );
echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath( 'js\jquery-jqGrid\jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0\js\jquery.jqGrid.src.js' ) );
echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath( 'js\myScript.js' ) )
```

How ever, I get an error when trying to do

```
$( document).ready( function( ) {
jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({
    url:'editing.php?q=1',
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Closed','Ship via','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:80,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:90,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:60, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:60, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:60,align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'closed',index:'closed',width:55,align:'center',editable:true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions:{value:"Yes:No"}},
        {name:'ship_via',index:'ship_via',width:70, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;TN:TNT"}},
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:100, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"20"}}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pagered',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Editing Example",
    editurl:"someurl.php"
});
$("#bedata").click(function(){
    var gr = jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null ) jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
    else alert("Please Select Row");
});
```

The selector #editgrid is good, and myScript is included, so as the other files

Comment: does `jQuery("#editgrid")` return required element? And also which line is the error shown at?

Comment: jest jQuery("#editgrid") is returning the element

Comment: the error is right below jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({

Comment: In grid.locale-en.js it says that jQuery is not defined, but I included it.

Comment: one way to be sure is look at the page source and then try to open the js links, they should be click-able links in Mozilla, you may have included them but are they 404, linked correctly.

Comment: add modal and dnr libraries also

Answer (score 0):

Your missing including the language file in your JavaScript includes.

~ src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js

You'll probably also want jquery-ui.js and the associated .css files.

Comment: I added it right now, but I still get the same error

Comment: I think it has to go before the jqgrid script too. That was one issue, may or may not fix your problem.

Comment: Not working, btw I downloaded 4.6. I specified the jquery-ui css, jqGrid css, locale and the jqGrid